# Calling getState Model method in a custom model method

Tags: model, joomla-5.x

I have a method in a model and I need the array of state variables. In controller it's easy, simply get an $model object and get the array with

```
$state = $model->getState();
```

But in a model all my test always get an error 0 or 503:

```
class MyModel extends ListModel
{
...
    public function setFiltrosActivos()
    {
        $state = $this->getState();  // 503 error
    }
}
```

Please, how can I get the state variables in a method inside a model?

Comment: Issue not reproducible. Post the error message and stack trace.

Comment: Sorry, I only receive a server error with 503 Service Unavailable. The server is temporarily busy, try again later!. No stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I chose to move the entire method from the model to a helper and perform the logic there. Now it's working fine. Thank you.

```
$model  = Factory::getApplication()->bootComponent('com_mycomponent')->getMVCFactory()->createModel('mymodel', 'Site');
$state = $model->getState();
```

Comment: Please accept your answer as the chosen solution.

Comment: Glad you solved your issue. But this is a bad answer. It does not explain how or why it works and why original code did not work. Calling `getState()` from within the model should work without issues - it does across the entire CMS. The only thing that could be causing the issue is calling the the method inside `populateState()` method  which would result in recursion, as per documentation.

Comment: Really I don't know why this problem has occurred. Your answer have complete sense., thanks again.

Comment: @Irata. Yes, I tried to accept the answer yesterday but it is necessary to wait 24 hours according to forum rules.